# Swift Module stability: Module compiled with Swift X.Y cannot be imported by the Swift X.Z compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode12

Let's start by existing questions,

[Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654714/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-2-compiler)

[Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114718/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-0-compiler)

[Module compiled with Swift 5.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409713/module-compiled-with-swift-5-1-2-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-2-4-compiler)

And, now with XCode 12(12A7209)

> Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3
> compiler

The framework was compiled in the lower version of Swift (Swift 5.2.4). However, it worked perfectly with XCode 12 beta.

**Solution tried:**

- Setting `Build Libraries for Distribution` to `Yes`
- [Shipping Binary Frameworks With Swift 5.0](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/shipping-binary-frameworks-with-swift-5-0/)

Whole point is the Swift ABI stability for binary framework and how to achieve it across different swift version.

Please advice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `.swiftmodule` folder of prebuilt framework contain `.swiftinterface` file?

Comment: @Eugene Dudnyk Yes it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Module Stability, not ABI stability.

The difference and the way how to achieve Module Stability, are described here: https://www.donnywals.com/what-is-module-stability-in-swift-and-why-should-you-care/

Here is [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/) that explains swift binary frameworks (time code: 17:00).

Briefly, your framework

- should be built with `Build Libraries for Distribution` set to `Yes`
- set the `Skip Install` property to `No`.
- distributed as `.xcframework` with variants for simulator and device

You'll need to ensure that frameworks embedded into `.xcframework` all have `.swiftinterface` file inside of `Modules/<name>.swiftmodule` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the revert. Let me try out the solution.